# Control a Wordpress plugin auto-update rate time

Tags: plugin-development, automatic-updates

I am writing a plugin, I want, in some cases, to tell WordPress to update that plugin, and that plugin only, immediately.

I know that there is a transient called `update_plugins` that contains the latest time the plugin was updated. and from that value, WordPress checks if 12 hours have passed.

I have tried to manually change that value in order to fool WordPress into thinking the last update happened more than 12 hours ago and therefore trriger a new update check
But that didn't work, The value in the transient is changed but the update is not triggered.

This is the code I used:

```
$update_plugins = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );
$update_plugins->last_checked = $update_plugins->last_checked - 86400;
set_site_transient( 'update_plugins', $value );
```

What can I do to change the WordPress auto-update rate?
Is there a hook I can use?